# HTML relative positioning in Adobe AIR

Tags: air, webkit

I cannot get the flash.html.HTMLLoader class in AIR 3.1 to correctly position a HTML div element with position:relative.

According to my understanding (see step 4 of http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) and how Safari renders it, setting a div to relative positioning should cause it to maintain is position in the document flow (where it would be if it were position:static), but then allow child divs to be positioned absolutely relative to that div.

In AIR3.1, setting a div to position:relative positions is to the closest parent with position:absolute, not the position it should have in the document flow.

Is there a way to the specific version of webkit used by AIR3.1 to get around this, or am I out of luck?